# Ruby count integers in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

Is there a way I can count the number of integers in an array?  I have an array whose members come from `a-z` and `0-9`.  I want to count the number of integers in said array.  I tried:

```
myarray.count(/\d/)
```

...but the `count` method doesn't regex.

```
a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')
a << [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
t = a.sample(10)
p t.count(/\d/)  # show me how many integers in here
```

Comment: `count(obj)` uses `==` to count the number of elements equal to obj. So unless you're counting an array of regular expressions your code won't work. Moreover if it did work it still wouldn't count the integers because regex is used with strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should return the number of integers present within the array:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3].count { |e| e.is_a? Integer }
# => 3
```

Since `#count` can accept a block, we have it check if an element is an `Integer`, if so it will be counted towards our returned total.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Shorter version: `['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3].grep(Integer)`.